# Swift iOS prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, swift

Estoy empezando recién con Swift y tengo un duda. Tengo un `controlador_uno`: `UIViewController` y otro `controlador_dos`: `UITableViewController`.

La cosa es que mando una varible por segue desde `controlador_uno` al dos y en el `controlador_dos` no lo toma.

controlador_uno: UIViewController

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoreboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
 {
  if segue.identifier == "SendDataSearch"  
  {
    if let destino = segue.destinationViewController as ? Controlador_dos
    {
       destino.varSegue = txtNom.text
    }
  }
}
```

controlador_dos: UIUITableViewController{

```
var varSegue = ""

...
}
```

¿Se puede pasar variables de `UIViewController` a `UITableViewController`? He hecho cosas de `tableviewcontroller` a `viewController` y funcionan.

Answer (score 2):

Lo primero es asegurarte de que el nombre del `segue` esta bien escrito, puedes poner un punto de interrupción en el `init` del `controlador_dos` y verás si realmente llega hasta ahí. Una vez que te que asegures de que llegas.
Yo definiría el `varsegue` de esta forma, sin asignarle valor:

```
var varSegue : String?
```

EL `prepareForSegue` solo va en una dirección.

Answer (score 1):

Es muy probable que el problema venga porque `segue.identifier` te viene vacío, y cuando haces los `if` para comprobar que sea `SendDataSearch` y que el `Controlador_Dos` exista no llega a entrar en el primer `if`.
Por tanto, verifica que has puesto correctamente el `identifier` de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar te recomendaría darle una mejor forma al código:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "SendDataSearch"  {
        let destino = segue.destinationViewController as ? Controlador_dos

        destino!.varSegue = txtNom.text  
    }
}
```

Tengo una duda, cuando tu te refieres a `txtNom.text`, ¿a qué dato te refieres? Este podría ser un fallo.

Otro es como ya te comentaban anteriormente el hecho de no haberle dado un identifier a la segue en el storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

esto posiblemente te sirva:
- Enlaza el campo o la etiqueta a la cual asignarás el valor:

```
@IBOutlet weak var labeInfo: UILabel!
```

or

```
@IBOutlet weak var cmpInfo: UITextField!
```

- En la vista destino inicializa una variable del tipo que tomará tu campo de texto o bien incluso una etiqueta:

  var infoVAlue : String!

Luego en el constructor de la vista destino inicializa el campo con el valor de la variable:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    cmpInfo.text = infoVAlue
    //labeInfo.text = infoVAlue
```

//

Desde la vista origen en el "prepare segue"

```
   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard let goVC = segue.destination as? DestinationViewController else{return}
    goVC.infoVAlue = "Valor a Enviar"

}

}
```

Espero sirva de algo